# No data in scraping through scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Below is the code along with url of the site I m trying to get data from, but programs runs writing nothing to csv output file. Also, I got the xpath from chrome inspector console, so must be correct.

Here is the code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from insta.items import Insta

class instagram(CrawlSpider):
    name = "instagram"
    allowed_domains = ["zymanga.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://zymanga.com/millionplus/%sf' % page for page in range(1,163)]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="username"]/')

        items = []
        for title in titles:
            item = Insta()
            item["username"] = title.select("a/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

Comment: Try to `yield` instead of `return`

Comment: Have already tried, produces nothing...

Comment: Have you tried your xpaths in the shell?

Comment: You can't access the data if you are not logged in to the site (try with a private navigator). Check [this](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=login#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests)